# Tuples and List Manipulation with Python. Cutting Tuple generation short

Tags: python, list, variables, tuples

Really stuck with this question in my homework assignment.

Everything works, but when there is a space (`' '`) in the `p`. I need to stop the process of creating `can`.

For example, if I submit:

```
rankedVote("21 4", [('AB', '132'), ('C D', ''), ('EFG', ''), ('HJ K', '2  1')])
```

I would like to have:

```
['C D', 'AB']
```

returned, rather than just `[]` like it is now.

Code as below:

```
def rankedVote(p,cs):
    candsplit = zip(*cs)
    cand = candsplit[0]
    vote = list(p)
    ppl = vote
    can = list(p)
    for i in range(len(vote)):
        if ' ' in vote[i-1]:
            return []
        else:
            vote[i] = int(vote[i])
            can[vote[i]-1] = cand[i]

    for i in range(len(vote)):
        for j in range(len(vote)):
            if i != j:
                if vote[i] == vote[j]:
                    return []
    return can
```

**EDIT:**

In the example:

```
rankedVote("21 4", [('AB', '132'), ('C D', ''), ('EFG', ''), ('HJ K', '2  1')])
```

This means that the 1st, `AB` becomes 2nd,
and the 2nd one `C D` becomes 1st,
and it should stop because 3rd does not exist.

Let's say that instead of `21 4`, it was `2143`.
It would mean that the 3rd one `EFG` would be 4th,
and the 4th `HJ K` would be 3rd.

Comment: Could you describe, in words, exactly what each part of each argument to `rankedVote` means, and exactly what it is that the function is supposed to output, and what the parts of the output thing mean?

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing as you instructed I would say. Look at the code block below:

```
if ' ' in vote[i-1]:
            return []
```

Comment: I know that, but I am stuck of what to put in this code block so that it will just return everything up to just before the space.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I found it interesting.

Like the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844070/590904) said you aren't returning the list up to that point, you are returning `[]`.

What you should do is:

```
if ' ' in vote[i]:
    return can[:i]
```

Also, since you seemed to know how to use `zip`, you could have also done it this way:

```
def rankedVote(p,cs):
    cand = zip(*cs)[0]

    # get elements before ' ' 
    votes = p.split()[0] # '21'

    # map votes index order with corresponding list order
    # (number of `cands` is determined by length of `votes`)
    cans = zip(votes, cand) # [('2', 'AB'), ('1', 'C D')]

    # Sort the results and print only the cands
    result = [can for vote, can in sorted(cans)] # ['C D', 'AB']
    return result
```

Output:

```
>> rankedVote("21 4", [('AB', '132'), ('C D', ''), ('EFG', ''), ('HJ K', '2  1')])
['C D', 'AB']
>> rankedVote("2143", [('AB', '132'), ('C D', ''), ('EFG', ''), ('HJ K', '2  1')])
['C D', 'AB', 'HJ K', 'EFG']
```